# Why is the filter function not working in excel?

Tags: excel, filterfunction

The excel filter function is not available. When I type =Filter instead I get =filterxml only. Forcing it such as `=FILTER(B5:D14,D5:D14=H2,"No results")` gives an error filter function is not valid. Not sure why.

I am using Office 2016.

Comment: `FILTER` is a Google Sheets function. It is not an Excel function. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to filter results that match the given condition. For example, from students and age columns, I want to get filter students whose age is between a and b ages.

Comment: At present, the Excel `FILTER` function is only available to some Office 365 insiders.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld whoa cool didn't know that, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What's the other way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

I don't have much to work with so I'm doing this blind. But say you have your data starting in `A1`. In VBA you want the `Autofilter` function.

It would work something like this if you wanted to filter students who were over the age of 15, assuming age is in column B.

```
Sub Filter()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Autofilter, _
    Field:=2, _
    Criteria1:=">15"
End Sub
```

You can also make those conditions variables depending how you set it up, such as a cell where you type the age criteria and a data validation for which operator to use or which column to filter.

[You can read more about this function here](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-autofilter/)